# Where to get information on FAA AIXM 5.0 versions of Special Activity Airpace (SAA) files?

Tags: datasets

Does anybody know where to find documentation or someone to ask questions about the SAA database provided by the National Flight Data Center? I have some questions about the ambiguity of some of the data.

Or better yet, is there a better source for the boundaries and meta data for special-use airspace?

Comment: I guess you may ask [the National Flight Data Centerwhich publishes the data](https://nfdc.faa.gov/xwiki/bin/view/NFDC/56DaySub-2015-06-25). Email for NFDC Support Desk is [here](https://nfdc.faa.gov/portal/login.do;jsessionid=92B164784C873492E3D95901CD7F50F5).

Comment: They have a support desk? Cool. Didn't think to look for that.

Comment: Actually, the link you gave just takes me to the login page. But I'll poke around...

Comment: The second link gives you the email of the NFDC support desk (below the login fields). I do not publish the email here due to spam possibility.

Comment: d'oh! I see it now. I thought I needed to log in first.

Comment: Mins, The fellow at the help desk was very nice and sent me the document I needed to finish my product. Thank you. Make your comment an answer and I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: I'm glad you got your documentation. I'll write an answer, that can help other readers. Thanks a lot for having taken the time to provide a feedback to the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to contact the FAA [National Flight Data Center (NFDC)](https://nfdc.faa.gov/xwiki/bin/view/NFDC/56DaySub-2015-06-25). They provide information as part of the US Aeronautical Information Services (AIS).

NFDC Support Desk email is available on [this login page](https://nfdc.faa.gov/portal/login.do), below the login data boxes.

See also this question: [Where to find a waypoints/fixed points, navaids, airports database](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9681/where-to-find-a-waypoints-fixed-points-navaids-airports-database) for other aeronautical data sets in case you need them too.